# How do i change the column type in Numbers from number to string

Tags: numbers

I have a column in numbers with zipcodes. The zipcodes have leading zeros, only the column drops the leading zeros.

I assume this is because the column thinks it's a number and not a string.

I tried right clicking on the column header to get a menu item to to change the type but couldn't find anything.

How can I change the column type from number to string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Highlight the cells you want to change.
2. Click the paintbrush icon to display the Formatting sidebar.
3. In the `Data Format` dropdown, select `Text`